# How to debug environment variable that works locally doesn't work in production on Vercel

Tags: environment-variables, vercel

I'm trying to use the Sendgrid email API to send messages via a form. I have the API key stored in an .env.local file that works fine locally.

But when I deploy it on Vercel it stops working. I've added it in my environment variables on the site dashboard on Vercel with the same title and value as it appears locally.

The site is on Vercel over here:
https://forward-dev.vercel.app/find

I don't really know where to begin debugging it. Any help appreciated.